# NSLog macro that can take only one argument

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslog

```
#define LogMsg(msg) ((DebugMode)?NSLog(@"<%@:%@:%d:%@>", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), __LINE__,msg):NO)
```

With this macro I can print out:

```
LogMsg(@"Test");
```

Or

```
NSArray *testArray = @[@"one",@"two"];
LogMsg(testArray);
```

How can I do the same with a macro replacement that will also take two arguments like NSLog and still be able to print the array in the form I'm doing with the above?
example:

`NSLog (@"test: %@",test);`

- I'd prefer not using a 3rd party Class for that and solve the above with a macro.

Comment: Your first example `NSLog(testArray)` is not correct, and crashes at runtime. The first argument must be the format string.

Comment: I totally messed up this question. I've updated the question with the right macro I'm using.

Comment: Can you also post the Macro of __LINE__ please?

Comment: There is no macro for LINE

Comment: There are some tricks can be used to find out the number of arguments for a macro and base on it choose different macro to expand. But I can't remember how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
#define LogMsg(msg, ...) ((DebugMode)?NSLog(@"<%@:%@:%d>" msg, NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__):NO)
```

It uses preprocessor string concatenation `@"<%@:%@:%d>" msg` to get a "combined format string" with the fixed and the variable part, 
and [preprocessor variadic macros](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html) with `##__VA_ARGS__`.

*Added:* I don't think that is possible to define a macro such that both

```
LogMsg(someObject);
LogMsg(formatString, arg1, arg2, ...);
```

work.

Comment: When trying to `LogMsg(testArray);` I'm getting an error `Expected ')'`

Comment: @Sha: You have to start with a format string: `LogMsg (@"test: %@",test)`.

Comment: That's the point of the question :). I don't want to use a format string. I want to be able to use it sometimes like this `LogMsg(testArray);` and sometimes like this: `LogMsg(@"test %@",someObject);` Is that possible?

Comment: @Sha: I don't think that is possible with a macro.

Comment: Thanks. Please edit your last comment to the answer so I can accept if no working solution will be posted.

Answer (score 0):

So close! Your macro works with the following invocations:

```
ALog("Test");
NSArray *testArray = @[@"one",@"two"];
ALog("%@", testArray);
```

The compiler will automatically concatenate:

```
@"%s [Line %d] " "Test"
```

to:

```
@"%s [Line %d] Test"
```